# How to sort this array of results?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

Here is my query that attempts to sort an array of MongoDB documents based on a derived field called `expiresAt`. `expiresAt` is a Date object that represents the date string stored in `doc.expirationDate`.

It fails with an error `TypeError: ... .sort({}) is not a function (shell):5`

```
db.tokens.find().map(function(doc) {
    var expiryDate = new Date(doc.credentialsMap.linkedin.expirationDate);
    doc.expiresAt = expiryDate;
    return doc;
    }).sort({'expiresAt': -1});
```

What am I doing wrong? It's unclear to me exactly what return type [`map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/cursor.map/) provides. If it's a cursor then why isn't `sort` supported? It's clearly available in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/cursor.sort/).

Comment: I have triple checked my Mongo version. `mongod --version
db version v2.4.10`

Answer (score 1):

[`cursor.map()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor-map) returns a Java script array.

The way you're calling `sort()` assumes that the return value is a `MongoDB` cursor, that's why it fails.

You'd have to use the regular `Array.sort` syntax. 
For example, to have your map results sorted in descending order, use the following:

```
db.tokens.find().map(function(doc) {
var expiryDate = new Date(doc.credentialsMap.linkedin.expirationDate);
doc.expiresAt = expiryDate;
return doc;
}).sort(function(a,b) { return b.expiresAt - a.expiresAt});
```